Does $H^{1/2}$-norm-convergence imply $L^{\infty}$-norm-convergence on $H^{1/2} \cap L^{\infty} (\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{T})$?
My question is the following:
Let $f_n \in (H^{1/2} \cap L^{\infty}) (\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{T})$ and let $f_n \to f$ in $||\cdot||_{H^{1/2}}$. Does this also imply that $f_n \to f$ in $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$?
The standard counterexamples by sequences of indicator funtion don't work, because they are not elements of $(H^{1/2} \cap L^{\infty}) (\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{T})$. Also the usual elements $g \in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{C}), g \notin L^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{C})$ cannot be produced.
The difficulties lay in the correspondence of the $H^{1/2}$-norm, which is expressed in terms of Fourier coefficients or as an integral, and the $L^{\infty}$-norm.
In other words: Does the norm $\max(|| \cdot ||_{\infty}, ||\cdot||_{H^{1/2}})$ and the norm $||\cdot||_{H^{1/2}}$ imply the same topology on that unitary loop group?
